# ASP.NET Empty Label Text

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, label, hiddenfield

I am using set value with jquery but i couldn't get value from label 
**jquery code** is here

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input:radio[name=paketler]").click(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $('#<%=lblradio.ClientID%>').html(value);
        });
    })
```

i used **hiddenfield**,`.val(),.text()` but i am seeing text value on label but i couldn't get value in **codebehind**. can you help me ? how can i get value in **codebehind**.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle demo

Comment: i am using asp.net. jquery code is working but i couldn't get value in codebehind

Comment: Can you post the `label` id of any label here from rendered html?? Are you using `MasterPage`?

Comment: @Ahmet can you please post your html code for this?

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$('#' +'<%=lblradio.ClientID %>').val(value);
```

or

```
$('#<%=lblradio.ClientID %>').val(value);
```